# How to Use JQuery to Store Session ID from HTTP Response?

Tags: jquery

I am making HTTP requests to a web service that requires authentication.  My intiial request is as follows:

```
function getReq() {
$.ajax( {
   type: "GET",
   url: urlRequest,
   dataType: jsonp,
   cache: false,
   // success: getRates,
   error: onFaultAjaxRequest,
   timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_AJAX_REQUEST
});
}
```

The urlRequest contains the base address plus a querystring with my username and password.  The HTTP response resulting in this request includes a session ID.  This session ID is used in subsequent HTTP requests to the web service.

How do I trap the session ID using JQuery or another alternative method?

When I receive the second response with my currency data, how do I utilize JQuery CSV plugin to create an array from the data returned in CSV format?

Thanks,
Sid

**Edit** Based on responses thus far, here's what I have written for my js file:

```
var urlRequest = "http://webrates.truefx.com/rates/connect.html?u=user&p=pass&f=html&q=dfrates"
var DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_AJAX_REQUEST = 33000; //in milisecond
var DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_AFTER_SUCCESS_REQUEST = 330; //time after succes request before next request

function getReq() {
$.ajax( {
   type: "GET",
   url: urlRequest,
   dataType: jsonp,
   cache: false,
   success: getRates,
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.withCredentials=true;
            },
   error: onFaultAjaxRequest,
   timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_AJAX_REQUEST
});
}

function getRates(){
var tab=jXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
}

function onFaultAjaxRequest(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
var t = setTimeout(getReq, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_AFTER_SUCCESS_REQUEST);
}

function onSuccessAjaxRequest(returnData) {
var obj= getReq;
var arr=$.makearray(obj);

};
```

My index.html page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to MyDomain.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dfc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.jqplot('chartdiv'[onSuccessAjaxRequest]);
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chartdiv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I debug index.html, I receive an error stating JScript error "No Data Specified" in the jqplot plugin.  How should I remedy this situation?

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about something like this:

```
function getReq() {
$.ajax( {
   type: "GET",
   url: urlRequest,
   dataType: jsonp,
   cache: false,
   success: getRates,
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
           xhr.withCredentials = true;
        },
   error: onFaultAjaxRequest,
   timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_AJAX_REQUEST
});
}


function getRates(data, textStatus, jXHR) {
    var tab=jXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
    // tab is a string with headers ...
}
```

However, there are cross-domain and browser issues. For examle, firefox 3.5 (or jquery) seems to clear Set-Cookie field, so it's empty in javaScript. When connecting to other domain, xhr.withCredentials=true has to be set also.

Comment: To clarify, I should create a new function getAllResponseHeaders and use the success: data, textStatus,jXHR syntax you mention?  Then, wire up getReq success to be getAllResponseHeaders?  Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out `$("div#data).data("UID",UID)` to store the session id.
 http://forum.jquery.com/topic/data-session-variable-or-cookie. Personally I never used session IDs in client side because sessions IDs are part of url and not the query string, in java see JSESSIONID, see where the question mark `?` is in url. It is after sessionid. You dont have to handle it browsers will send it when session will be established.